# Запрос в БД IS NOT NULL не работает

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, null

Почему все равно выводит значения с NULL???
`SELECT * FROM words WHERE 648226895  IS NOT NULL LIMIT 5`

Comment: 648226895  это название столбца такое?

Comment: Да, но пробовал на любых столбцах, та же история.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз уж `648226895` - это название столбца, то тут предлагаю два варианта решения

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE [648226895]  IS NOT NULL
```

и

```
SELECT * FROM words w WHERE w.[648226895]  IS NOT NULL
```

Или проще говоря, с такими *интересными* (т.е. в данном случае столбцов, начинающихся с числа) требуется `[]` вокруг их названия